# Unable to create a new Dialogflow agent through the console

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am unable to create a new Dialogflow agent through the console. When I select the agent's name and click on "Create", the button changes to "Working" for a few seconds and then says "Cancelled".
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are could be a few reasons for that:

1. You have selected the wrong Could Project. GCP limits one agent per project, you cannot select a project that is already connected to Dialogflow
2. If you are creating a new Google project for your new agent, you probably have reached your limit with projects per billing account. You can check this by disabling billing for some of your projects and try to create again.
3. There are some limitations for naming agents as well [[here]](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas)